# New variable calculated on number of unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I need to count in my dataframe the unique values in customer_unique_id and create a new column/variable counting the number of time a customer_unique_id appears, drop rows to only keep one customer_unique_id and eventually create a new category variable.

The Dataframe :

```
customer_unique_id       order_id        category
   ef54                     '0024'           gift
   ab58                     '0587'         school
   yg41                     '0678'           gift
   af48                     '0469'           gift
   ef54                     '8514'         school
   af48                     '2771'           gift
```

The expected Dataframe output :

```
     customer_unique_id       order_id        category    number_of_orders      category_2
       ef54                     '0024'           gift            2                 school
       ab58                     '0587'         school            1                 Nan
       yg41                     '0678'           gift            1                 Nan
       af48                     '0469'           gift            2                 gift
```

The most important for me is to understand how to create the variable numer_of_orders, but category_2 would be a bonus.

I don't have more than two orders per customer_unique_id.

Comment: maybe look into using pd.DataFrame.groupby.transform : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can groupby and count, in addition to groupby first, and merge them...

```
csv = io.StringIO('''customer_unique_id       order_id        category
   ef54                     '0024'           gift
   ab58                     '0587'         school
   yg41                     '0678'           gift
   af48                     '0469'           gift
   ef54                     '8514'         school
   af48                     '2771'           gift''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv,sep=r'\s+')
agg_df = df.groupby(['customer_unique_id'],as_index=False).first()
seconds = df.groupby(['customer_unique_id'],as_index=False).nth(1)[['customer_unique_id','category']]
agg_df = agg_df.merge(seconds,on=['customer_unique_id'],how='left')
agg_df['number_of_orders'] = df.groupby(['customer_unique_id'])['category'].count().values
>>>agg_df

    customer_unique_id  order_id    category_x  category_y  number_of_orders
0   ab58                '0587'      school      NaN         1
1   af48                '0469'      gift        gift        2
2   ef54                '0024'      gift        school      2
3   yg41                '0678'      gift        NaN         1
```

if you want to rename index as the example, do:

```
agg_df.columns =['customer_unique_id order_id category category_2 number_of_orders'.split()]
>>> agg_df

    customer_unique_id  order_id    category    category_2  number_of_orders
0   ab58                '0587'      school      NaN         1
1   af48                '0469'      gift        gift        2
2   ef54                '0024'      gift        school      2
3   yg41                '0678'      gift        NaN         1
```

Note: the expected output isnt make sense because there is 3 time school, or  M I missing somthing?

Comment: You are right my mistake! af48 get gift two times and not one time gift and one time school!
Sorry!

Comment: It raises an error :
ValueError: Length of values (94087) does not match length of index (97544)

Comment: i made some changes can you test it now?